# Documents List API client for C# timing out

Tags: c#, google-docs-api

I'm working on a simple wrapper for the google docs api in c#. The problem I'm running into is my tests are timing out. Sometimes. When I run all of my tests (only 12 of them) then it usually hangs up on the 8th one, which is testing the delete function. After about 6.5 minutes, it continues on, but every test after it also times out after 6.5 minutes for each test. If I run the tests individually then it works fine every time.

Here is the first method that times out:

Updated to show exception handling

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanDeleteFile()
{
    var api = CreateApi();
    api.UploadFile("pic.jpg", "..\\..\\..\\pic.jpg", "image/jpeg");
    try
    {
        var files = api.GetDocuments();
        api.DeleteFile("pic.jpg");
        var lessFiles = api.GetDocuments();
        Assert.AreEqual(files.Count - 1, lessFiles.Count);
    }
    catch (Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException ex)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("..\\..\\..\\errors.log", true))
        {
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            writer.WriteLine(time + ":\r\n\t" + ex.ResponseString);
        }
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

It times out on `var lessFiles = api.GetDocuments();` The second call to that method. I have other methods that call that method twice, and they don't time out, but this one does.

The method that all the test methods use that times out:

```
    public AtomEntryCollection GetDocuments(DocumentType type = DocumentType.All, bool includeFolders = false)
    {
        checkToken();
        DocumentsListQuery query = getQueryByType(type);
        query.ShowFolders = includeFolders;
        DocumentsFeed feed = service.Query(query);
        return feed.Entries;
    }
```

It times out on this line `DocumentsFeed feed = service.Query(query);`. This would be closer to acceptable if I was requesting insane numbers of files. I'm not. I'm requesting 5 - 6 depending on what test I'm running.

Things I've tried:

- Deleting all files from my google docs account, leaving only 1-2 files depending on  the test for it to retrieve.
- Running the tests individually (they all pass and nothing times out, but I shouldn't have to do this)
- Checking my network speed to make sure it's not horribly slow (15mbps down 4.5mbps up)

I'm out of ideas. If anyone knows why it might start timing out on me? Any suggestions are welcome.

**edit**

As @gowansg suggested, I implemented exponential backoff in my code. It started failing at the same point with the same exception. I then wrote a test to send 10000 requests for a complete list of all documents in my drive. It passed without any issues without using exponential backoff. Next I modified my test class so it would keep track of how many requests were sent. My tests crash on request 11.

The complete exception:

```
Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException was unhandled by user code
Message=Execution of request failed: https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full
Source=GoogleDrive
StackTrace:
     at GoogleDrive.GoogleDriveApi.GetDocuments(DocumentType type, Boolean includeFolders) in C:\Users\nlong\Desktop\projects\GoogleDrive\GoogleDrive\GoogleDriveApi.cs:line 105
     at GoogleDrive.Test.GoogleDriveTests.CanDeleteFile() in C:\Users\nlong\Desktop\projects\GoogleDrive\GoogleDrive.Test\GoogleDriveTests.cs:line 77
InnerException: System.Net.WebException
     Message=The operation has timed out
     Source=System
     StackTrace:
          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
          at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
     InnerException:
```

**another edit**

It seems that I only crash after requesting the number of documents after the second upload. I'm not sure why that is, but I'm definitely going to look into my upload method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your tests pass when ran individually, but not when ran consecutively then you may be hitting a request rate limit.  I noticed in your comment to JotaBe's answer you mentioned were getting request timeout exceptions.  You should take a look at the http status code to figure out [what to do](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#handling_api_errors).  In the case of a 503 you should implement [exceptional back off](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#implementing_exponential_backoff).

**Updated Suggestion**

Place a `try-catch` around the line that is throwing the exception and catch the `Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException`.  According to the [source](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/exceptions.cs) there are two properties that may be of value to you:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// this is the error message returned by the server
    /// </summary>
    public string ResponseString
    { ... }
```

and

```
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// <summary>Read only accessor for response</summary>
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public WebResponse Response
    { ... }
```

Hopefully these contain some useful information for you, e.g., an HTTP Status Code.

Comment: I'll try that when I get in to work tomorrow. Sounds like it could be what I'm looking for

Comment: that didn't work either. I've edited my question to reflect that

Comment: It's not very often that I sit and stare at my tests waiting for one of them to fail, but now they are all passing even though I made sure to throw the exception after I handled it. Hopefully it will fail again so I can get some information out of it.

Comment: That's strange that the test would pass when an exception is being thrown.  Would you mind updating your answer with your try-catch code?

Comment: The exception is never getting thrown. Everything is working perfectly. I'm not sure what happened, but I'll update my question

Comment: That same try catch block is around every test that uploads a file

Comment: This is off topic but you should get used using `throw;` not `throw ex;`.  `throw ex;` clobbers the stack trace and makes it appear the exception is being thrown from the line you called `throw ex;` from. `throw;` will leave the stack trace intact.  It's not hurting anything in this particular scenario, but I thought I'd mention for when you need to re-throw exceptions in the future.

Comment: If the exception only occurs when there is no try-catch you could try removing the try-catch and setting a breakpoint on the line that's throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the time-outs for your unit tests. Here you have extensive information on it:

- [How to: Set Time Limits for Running Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243175.aspx)

You can include `Thread.Sleep(miliseconds)` in your unit tests before the offending methods. Probably your requests are being rejected from google docs for being too may in too short a time.

Comment: That's definitely useful, 30 seconds is a lot more bearable a time to wait for a test to fail than 6.5 minutes is. But I'm more wondering why my requests to google are getting web request timeout exceptions than how to reduce the time to failure. Sorry if I wasn't clear